# Ring of mind-shielding against detect thoughts

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters

Say a doppelganger tries to read someone wearing a ring of mind shielding- does it read what the wearer wants it to think or does the wearer's mind come across as a blank void?

Answer (score 8):

**Neither.**

> While wearing this ring, you are immune to magic that allows other creatures to read your thoughts, determine whether you are lying, know your alignment, or know your creature type. Creatures can telepathically communicate with you only if you allow it.

This does not say anything about projecting false thoughts or even "your mind is an empty void"; it's just as if the magic failed for some other reason (saving throw, immunity to magic of some kind, blocked by the right amount of lead/stone/etc...). Someone trying to exercise mind reading just knows "I can't do it."

Comment: In HTTP error code terms, it's 403 Forbidden, not 404 Not Found

Comment: That might be overstating it, I'm not sure you can tell between a 403 and a 404 with this magic - trying to read with the ring vs trying to read someone mindless or an illusion, for example.  But it's not a 500 Internal Server Error or a deliberate honeypot.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, the person attempting to read the mind is aware that it isn't working, yes?

Comment: Yes, just not why.

Comment: Like my mother-in-law and her computer not working.  She knows it's not working, just not why. (So she calls my son to solve her problem ...)